# WCF service reject with error The server has rejected the client credentials

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx) guide i try to Host `WCF service` in a Windows Service Using `TCP`.
this works fine on my computer but when install this service in other computer in the same network got an error: The server has rejected the client credentials
I try to disable Firewall but still same error (and the service running...)
from the client side Add service reference works fine and recognize the service.
this is my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://192.168.0.100:8523/Service1 " />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

192.168.0.100 is the server machine IP address.

Comment: When you run the WinForm application (client), what credentials are you running it under?  You probably need to be running it under a domain account with admin priviledges.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this config for tcp binding:

```
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="customTcpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="20480000" transferMode="Streamed" >
      <security mode="None"></security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: That won't solve the problem.  OP will get a binding mismatch because the security won't match.  The service will be using the default security mode for `netTcpBinding`, which is "Transport".

Comment: Where i need to put this section ?